# Create dynamic table with textbox, dropdownlist and duplicate specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Great day community, i having problem on adding button, dropdownlist,textbox ,duplicate specific row and hidden specific row in dynamic table.

*For duplicate specific row in table start from **13** row to **17** row.*

*For hidden row is on row **4**.*

I'm able create dynamic table,and textbox right column but it should be on left column.

**Below is the javascript:**

```
function tableCreate() {
     var body = document.body,
         tbl  = document.createElement('table');
     txtbox = document.createElement('input');
     tbl.style.width  = '350px';
     tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

 for(var ix = 0; ix < 17; ix++){   // this loop will create 17 row 
     var tr = tbl.insertRow();
     var td = tr.insertCell();
     td.style.border = '1px solid black';
     td.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));  //create textbox here
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
 }
```

**Expected Result:**

table right side: text  |   table left side: textbox

table right side: text  |  table left side: dropdownlist

table right side: text  |   table left side: duplicate button for specific row

Comment: Can you share your code on Fiddle?

Comment: @KomalR update the link here https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewLead/rf4037wh/15/